# MySQL tables are markes as crashed after repair

Tags: linux, mysql

I've used myhotcopy to backup my MySQL databases. I had to recovery everything after a system crash, so I moved the files into the MySQL directory.

Now, every 1-2h the server seems to do an auto repair for some tables or anything like this. If I manually start a repair, the table will be marked as crashed after that.

Anyone knows, why this happens and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would mysqldump everything, move the db and innodb files somewhere safe, and reload from the dumps. Will likely take less time..

Could the mysqlhotcopy job the files originate from ever have run out of file descriptors/driven mysqld out of the same while dumping unattended? That is an extremely great way to get a subtly corrupt backup, mostly working, of a mysql installation. Mysqldump is similarly vulnerable by the way; any spurious errors when dumping should never be ignored as they often point to exactly that problem.

Comment: Dumped the whole DB and inserted it again. I'll let it run for a few hours and give you feedback then.

Comment: Both tables, which were marked as crashed before, are looking good for hours now. Thanks for the tip.